# <Section> Backgrounds floating apart/ over each other

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a landing page with several different sections like [chartbeat.com](http://chartbeat.com). I've done the following in my HTML:

```
    <section class="payroll">
      <p>
        This is the Payroll Section
      </p>
    </section><!-- END class="payroll" -->  

    <section class="pos">
      <p>
        This is the Point of Sale Section
      </p>
    </section><!-- END class="pos" -->
```

and this is what my CSS looks like:

```
    .payroll {
    background-image: url('../img/payroll_bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 100%;
}

.pos {
    background-image: url('../img/pos_bg.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The problem is the sections are floating apart, leaving a large gap between them. See picture. If I shrink the window, or inspect element, the sections float up to overlap each other.

Any ideas? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You should make sure there is no margin applied to your `section`s.

Comment: No margin added. That also wouldn't account for the sections floating over each other when the browser window shrinks.

Comment: I think the problem is being caused by your 100% heights. Is there a height set on the parent element that contains the two `section`s?

Comment: There isn't a height set on the parent elements. I changed the height: 100% to 581px, the size of the bg image and that solved the problem. I can't think of a reason why this will affect responsiveness of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is being caused by your 100% heights. You need to set a height on the parent element because any percentage dimensions are based on the size of it.

Moving away from percentages, like you have done, would also do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You're totally right. I'm still figuring out where it's appropriate to use percentages, and where I need to explicitly state the size.

Comment: No worries - percentages do have their uses but mainly for widths in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

create a .wrapper div and use this:

```
.wrapper {
width:100%; /* you can define as you want */
height:100%; /* you can define as you want */
position:relative;
}
.payroll {
background-image: url('../img/payroll_bg.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
height: 100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:0 auto;
}
.pos {
background-image: url('../img/pos_bg.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
height: 100%;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
opacity:0.9;
width:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: This works well to push the sections together, but if I add position absolute, the bg images overlap, which I don't want. I changed the height: 100% to the actual height of the bg images and that seems to solve the problem.